# How is a variable of type Variant with value Empty represented on the stack?

Tags: vbscript, stack, storage, rhino3d

The following explanation is from the [Rhino Developer Docs](https://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinoscript/nothing-empty-null/)

> ### Empty
>
> When you declare a variable in VBScript, the variable’s value before
>   the first assignment is undefined, or `Empty`.
>
> ```vb
> Dim varValue ' Empty value
> ```
>
> So basically, `Empty` says “I am an uninitialized variant.” If you need
>   to detect whether a variable actually is an empty variant and not a
>   string or a number, you can use `IsEmpty`. Alternatively, you could use
>   `TypeName` or `VarType`, but `IsEmpty` is best.

So `Empty` is used for declaring variables. If you declare a variable, you reserve storage at the stack, but what is the value of Empty on the Stack?

Comment: Everything has a default value except objects. However you need to read the docs as it says what you should do. So numbers are 0. Strings are tested by comparing to an empty string even though it's not really an empty string.

Comment: PS an empty string (a string with no characters in it) is different to a string that is empty (not initialised). An empty string is just `""` which is what the docs say to test for. That will match both an empty string and a string that is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VBScript variables are of type `Variant`. A variant represents a value that can change type. In memory, the Variant type is a 16 byte [structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-tagvariant).

If the variable is empty (`Empty` value), then the `vt` member (that stores the type of the data referenced by the variable) will have a value of `0x0000` ([`VT_EMPTY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237865.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by stack? VBScript's virtual machine stack or the CPU stack. For theCPU stack use a debugger

You can also start in a debugger.

windbg or ntsd (ntsd is a console program and maybe installed). Both are also from Debugging Tools For Windows.

Download and install Debugging Tools for Windows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363

Install the Windows SDK but just choose the debugging tools.

Create a folder called Symbols in C:\

Start `Windbg`. File menu - Symbol File Path and enter

```
srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

then

```
windbg -o -g -G c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k batfile.bat
```

All programs stop after loading but before starting to run the program. Press `g` to continue. Also programs stop after they finish running all code. Again press `g`.

You can press **F12** to stop it and `kb` will show the call stack (`g` continues the program). If there's errors it will also stop and show them.

Type `lm` to list loaded modules, `x *!*` to list the symbols and `bp [symbolname]` to set a breakpoint.

A breakpoint is where the program stops when it encounters the BP. Allowing you to read the stack. `kb` shows the callstack and the first 4 parameters to the functions.

**VB6**

If programming in VB6 then this environmental variable `link=/pdb:none` stores the symbols in the dll rather than separate files. Make sure you compile the program with No Optimisations and tick the box for Create Symbolic Debug Info. Both on the Compile tab in the Project's Properties.

Also CoClassSyms (http://microsoft.com/msj/0399/hood/hood0399.aspx) can make symbols from type libraries. 
.

See for background https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/04/19/runtime-typing-in-vbscript/

--