# VB6 executable crashes intermittently in windows 8 and 10 - Have questions re WinDbg

Tags: exception, vb6, windbg

I've debugged the code/compiler with WinDbg and it actually handled the exception. It seems to show the crash but I have no idea what the output means.

```
ModLoad: 72930000 72d35000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WININET.dll

(a38.cf0): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=034b0000 edx=00000000 esi=003e2000 
edi=7745d724
eip=774f80c9 esp=0019fa1c ebp=0019fa48 iopl=0  nv up ei pl zr na pe 
nc cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             
efl=00000246
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2b:
774f80c9 cc              int     3
0:000> g

ModLoad: 03bd0000 03c56000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SXS.DLL
```

Any help in understanding and resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: That looks like a breakpoint. Post the error message in full. The number, the description, and the source or dll.

Comment: ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2b:  is the standard system breakpoint stop  windbg has stopped after loading the process for you to examine  this is the standard entry for all executables

Comment: Also you have to compile VB6 with no optimisations (else you won't recognise common assembly patterns and your function calls turn into unnamed inline code). There is a standard breakpoint at program entry and exit. Here is a little primer on WinDBG and VB6. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439321/which-value-has-empty-on-the-stack/52440527#52440527

Comment: See *Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Security and Maintenance\Problem Details* and click your crash for details to post here.

Comment: There are no errors, both the exe and the vb6 compiler crash to the desktop.

Comment: If the compiler crashes and you debug it, but you don't own the MS source code of the compiler, how would you fix the problem?

Comment: Are you running the compiler As Administrator? If it is crashing there will be an error log as per prev message. If there isn't one it is not crashing. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

As i Commented what you have pasted in your query is the standard Starting point
for each and every executable that is loaded in windbg

you can load any executable and check it like this

```
C:\Windows>cdb -c "q" nuget.exe | tail -4
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c: <<<<<<<<<<<<<<   
77d805a6 cc              int     3
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'q'
quit:

C:\Windows>cdb -c "q" explorer.exe | tail -4
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c: <<<<<<<<<<<<  
77d805a6 cc              int     3
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'q'
quit:

C:\Windows>cdb -c "q" bfsvc.exe | tail -4
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c: <<<<<<<<<<<  
77d805a6 cc              int     3
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'q'
quit:

C:\Windows>
```

if you have a crash you need to provide the details of crash 
please start a new thread or edit this query  to add pertinent information

what you pasted are not the crash details

your application is probably crashing because of this

HEAP[Txxxxxxxh.exe]: HEAP: Free Heap block 0BA22450 modified at 0BA224B0 after it was freed

if windbg broke here look at the call stack using kb or run !analyze -v for pertinent info

what you uploaded contains mostly information output like module loads 
and some spurious desktop window manager dlls (ms binary )debug output
which is of absolutely no use for analysing crash

please go through some basic tutorials on how to use windbg

Comment: Here's a link to the entire WinDbg output: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1itd5XbLF_TvMfdlOCP-oZbkJQFMtuT9y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I compiled the code w/no optimizations and then ran WinDbg so there are 2 different logs for each of the exes

Comment: sorry the file contains mostly debug outputs of module loads which are not crash details  you probably have a delete() that is problematic you need to look at the call stack  what you uploaded is of no use except for the single line which says that a free block is freed again

Comment: @Taffman - the easiest way to get a meaningfull dump is by using procdump and have it monitor your VB6 process for exceptions (second and/or first chance exceptions). Something like this started from the command line should do: `procdump -ma -e 1 -n 100 -w vb6.exe`. This will wait for a vb6.exe programm, attach and create maximum 100 dumpfiles for each exception thrown by vb6.